# Capitalize 1 word or sentence in String inside Strings.xml

Tags: android

In strings.xml, I know I can bold and/or italicize part of the string like so:

```
<string name="my_string">Some string with a bunch of words <b><i>goes here</i></b>.</string>
```

My question:

Is there a similar way to capitalize an entire part of a string? something like:

```
<string name="my_string">Some string with a bunch of words <c>goes here</c>.</string>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just type the string GOES HERE?  Am I missing something?

Comment: because, in our real world case, the "goes here" will be a "%s" that we have to fill in on our side

Comment: Then why not upper case it before you plug it into the %s

Comment: future-proofing.  Right now, we pass values in from another string but we may be switching to getting the value from a server call later.  Want the current string to be able to handle it if we do

Comment: Then do a uppercase of the value from the server.  Trying to put it in the string template just isn't the way to do it.  Strings.xml is not a formatting engine.  If you want one of those, you need to do it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings), you can try to apply a CSS style:

```
<string name="my_string">Some string with a bunch of words <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">goes here</span>.</string>
```

*(See [text-transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-transform/).)*

I'm not sure what CSS styles android actually supports in `strings.xml` though.